Why try on produces a null in the console in dart?
class GuessGame {
  String name;

  GuessGame(this.name) {}

  startGame() {
    print('Add a number: ');
    try {
      int numberInput = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    } on FormatException {
      print('Invalid Input!');
    }
  }
}

When I add an invalid input, it prints an extra null:
Invalid Input!
null
I have changed this line from:
int? numberInput = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

to this:
int numberInput = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

The result is the same.

Please post a minimal but complete example that can reproduce the problem.  There are only two print statements in the code you've shown, and both of them print string literals and cannot possibly print "null".  Your problem is coming from somewhere else.
